# Any idea why my GitHub App manages to update the file content using the same service call on local and fails when I deploy it?

Tags: angular, typescript, github, github-api, github-app

This is the call that I am making to the Github Api.

```
updateFileContent(userName: string, repoName: string, folderName: string, fileName: string, content: any): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
            Authorization: 'token ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')
        })
    };
    return this.http.put<any>('https://api.github.com/repos/' + userName + '/' + repoName + '/contents/' + folderName + '/' + fileName, content, options);
}
```

So this piece of code works perfectly on my ASP.NET Core - Angular app when I run it on localhost. But fails and gives me a 403 forbidden "Resource not accessible by integration" error message when I try the same operation after I deploy the app on Azure Websites. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Maybe? https://github.community/t/resource-not-accessible-by-integration-when-requesting-github-pages-build-via-rest-api/13567

Comment: Will try it out and post the update here. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. The access token generated after the user login will not be able to access the GitHub API. We need a Personal Access Token generated to hit the API and make it work.

Comment: I'm currently dealing with this issue. How did you programmatically get the PAT for authorized users?